# Do all drives get formatted when I install new windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have Windows 8 32 bit and want to change it to 64 bit. When I try to do that, it says that all my files and programs will be deleted. I have 3 drives. C is full of programs and documents. D and E have other important data. I know that if I install Windows 64 bit now then my C drive, where windows is installed, will be completely erased! But can anyone tell me whether my data in the other 2 drives will be safe or do I have to make a backup? P.S all my drives are almost full, my external hard drive is also almost full.... so to make backup, I will have to ask help from a friend!

Comment: In previous versions of windows, the operating system only installed itself on the drive that you specified, the other drives were left untouched

Comment: if there is enough disk space, at least in my case, windowsi nstalled itself and just moved all the files to Windows.old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go ahead and upgrade/install. Installation will not touch your files on any other driver other that the drive where windows will install (in your case is C:/) .

Until you decide to manually delete partition or format partition , windows installation / or upgrade will not touch your other partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no backups already of your files, they aren't important anyway, are they?

Only your System partition will be affected by the change, the other partitions shouldn't be touched by the upgrade.

Comment: They are something like everything I downloaded or made for the past 10 years! Although they ain't top secret agency stuff! :P But Can I be sure that my data will remain safe?

Comment: You store your data without backups, so no, you can not be sure it is save. Upgrading your Windows 8 from 32 bit to 64 will be as save as installing a completely new OS on your C: drive. It will not touch your other partitions unless you tell it to do that.

Comment: -1. I'm more than a little sick of the sarcasm that always accompanies these "you must have a backup, cause your not an idiot right?" responses.

Comment: That is quite an interpretation. Although I was using sarcasm, I never implied that the OP was an idiot. However, it is a bit odd when someone suddenly starts worrying about data he's storing for 10 years (probably 90% of it never touched after downloading it) without any backups. It's not idiocy, it's hoarding.